# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have codeigniter application and I install the xamp latest version that have php7 and On previous version of xamp it was just fine. I try to open my application in newer version it generate the error. 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()`

[image]

I don't understand what the issue is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **mysql_** is removed from **PHP7**

Comment: mysql_pconnect() removed in PHP7

Comment: so how can I solve this now?

Comment: $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) for mysql_pconnect:

It is deprecated

start using mysqli_connect or PDO for database connection

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Comment: how can I use PDO?

Comment: refer here -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: for codeigniter, in your config file => $db['default']['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name';

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to config folder and open database.php file look for the line 

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

change it to,

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

and 

$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; to 

$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I try this method but gave so other errors..!

Comment: show what error

Comment: It say syntax error...! while it was okay on last version of xamp

Comment: I am working in codeigniter how can I do it in framework.

Comment: show me the contents of database.php in config folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122507/discussion-between-shoyeb-sheikh-and-nomanjaved).